# How to supply custom function from import for LinkedHashMap removeEldestEntry during init

Tags: java

Consider this initialization

```
    this.cache = new LinkedHashMap<K, V>(MAX_ENTRIES+1, .75F, true) {
        public boolean removeEldestEntry(Map.Entry eldest) {           
        }
    };
```

Is there a way to substitute `removeEldestEntry` with definition imported from another class?

The reason I want to do this is because I have a generic wrapper class that has an `executor` and a `cache`, but for different runnable task the `cache` store different info and thus require different behavior for `LinkedHashMap.removeEldestEntry`

Edit:

```
public class MyBufferService<K, V> {

    private ThreadPoolExecutor executor;
    private final Map cache;

    public MyBufferService(String buffName) {
        executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(1, // corePoolSize
                1, // maximumPoolSize
                60, TimeUnit.SECONDS, // keepAlive
                new LinkedBlockingQueue<>(10000), // workQueue
                new ThreadFactoryBuilder().setNameFormat(buffName + "-MyBufferService-thread-%d").build(), // factory
                new ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy() // rejected execution handler
        );

        this.cache = new LinkedHashMap<K, V>(1000, .75F, true) {
            public boolean removeEldestEntry(Map.Entry eldest) {
            }
        };
    }
}
```

In the code above `executor` accepts any class that implements `runnable` , so imagine you have 2 task that implment `runnable` and each wants to supply its own `removeEldestEntry` functionality when executed by the thread pool.

Is there a way to accomplish that?

Edit 2:

```
    private class BufferTask implements Runnable {

        private final String mystring;
        private final Map cache;

        BufferTask(String mystring, Map cache) throws NullPointerException {
            this.mystring = mystring;
            this.cache = cache;
        }
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                synchronized (this.cache) {
                    this.cache.put(this.mystring, "hi");
                }
            } catch (Throwable t) {
            }
        }
        public boolean removeEldestEntry(Map.Entry eldest) {
        }
    }
```

To goal is really to have each type of task supply its own `removeEldestEntry`

Edit 3:

Here is how I submit my task

```
public class BufferService<K, V>{

    public BufferService(String bufferName) {
        executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(1, // corePoolSize
            1, // maximumPoolSize
            keepAliveTimeSec, TimeUnit.SECONDS, // keepAlive
            new LinkedBlockingQueue<>(queueSize), // workQueue
            new ThreadFactoryBuilder().setNameFormat(bufferName + "-KafkaBufferService-thread-%d").build(), // factory
            new ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy() // rejected execution handler
        );

        this.cache = new LinkedHashMap<K, V>(MAX_ENTRIES+1, .75F, true) {
             public boolean removeEldestEntry(Map.Entry eldest) {
             }
        };
    }

    public void putDeferBufferTask(
            String myString) throws RejectedExecutionException, NullPointerException {
        executor.submit(new BufferTask(myString, this.cache));
    }

}
```

Comment: `definition imported from another class`: can you please elaborate or give example code that does that?

Comment: Good call, I updated my question.

Comment: I suspect that it's going to be hard to give an implementation of `removeEldestEntry(Map.Entry eldest)` that runs asynchronously without violating the contract of the superclass interface. Or would you return a dummy `boolean` after submitting the task to the executor?

Comment: Do you really mean that you want two separate tasks in two separate threads to decide both concurrently about the `removeEldestEntry` policy of the cache? **What do you want it for?** How are you planning to make it thread-safe?

Comment: My goal is to have each task type execute by  one `MyBufferService` , however, `MyBufferService` should be generic enough to be instantiate to accomodate different task

Comment: Following your latest edit, will each task have their own cache, or will they share the same cache? if the latter, you still have the problem of multiple threads fighting. And you still did not tell what you **really** want to reach. I still suspect the X-Y problem http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: Where and how you call the `executor.execute()` method?

Comment: each task has different cache, sorry I should of make it clearer, I want to buffer each task by type, and you might be right about xy problem, I am just trying to make the buffer service more generic since there is already 2 task that will be using it, and I can envision more task that will use it.

Comment: Please comment on my solution, if you think it solves your question. And please listen to this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0wxyOng0-14

Comment: Your Edit 3 and sentence "each task has different cache" do not comply. Now you may easily call the `putDeferBufferTask()` method twice on one single instance of `BufferService`, thus creating two tasks sharing the same cache.

Comment: sorory, I meant each type of task.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand properly your question, what you are searching for might be the *Strategy* pattern. By this you may inject any behavior.

```
public MyBufferService(String buffName, Predicate<Map.Entry> removeEldestEntryImplementation) {
    ... 
    this.cache = new LinkedHashMap<K, V>(1000, .75F, true) {
        public boolean removeEldestEntry(Map.Entry eldest) {
            return removeEldestEntryImplementation.test(eldest);
        }
    };
}
```

Don't get confused by the method name `test()`, I am just using the standard functional interface `Predicate` provided by the standard library which has the suitable signature.

Following your Edit 2, you may join it like this:

```
private class BufferTask implements Runnable, Predicate<Map.Entry> {
    ....
    private boolean removeEldestEntry(Map.Entry eldest) {
        // your mysterious code here
    }
    @Override
    public boolean test(Map.Entry eldest) {
        return removeEldestEntry(eldest);
    }
}
```

and then pass an instance of this class to the constructor of `MyBufferService`.

Comment: Can you perhaps add an example call to the constructor that sends a predicate running `test` as a task in the given `executor`? I believe that would make your answer more complete.

Comment: @ErnestKiwele Well, you are right, I missed this. I do not know where the OP's "own `removeEldestEntry` functionality" comes from. I do not know where he calls the `executor.execute()` method.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to pass the instance of `BufferTask` since i am using a `linkedBlockingQueue` to handle task submission, and each task is brand new instance of `BufferTask`